# ArrayAdapter(CheckFragment,int,ArrayList<String>) itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);

Tags: java, android-studio

it said here is some problem but I don't know what it is

```
items = new ArrayList<>();
   itemsAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
   listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
   setUpListViewListener();
    return v;
```

> ```
>  constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; CheckFragment cannot be converted to Context)
>     constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; CheckFragment cannot be converted to Context)
>     constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; CheckFragment cannot be converted to Context)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing your class `CheckFragment` instead of the `Context` parameter in `ArrayAdapter`. If `CheckFragment` extends a `Fragment`, you can call `new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);`